# call a function with arguments passed to a template function

Tags: c++, templates

How would i call a function with arguments passed to a template function?
im trying to add functions to a vector after i get it working so i can call all functions in that vector, kind of like a callback

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename... T>
void RunFunction(std::function<void> f, T... args)
{
    f(args);
}

void testFunction(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << (x + y);
    return;
}


int main()
{
    RunFunction(testFunction, 1, 3);
}
```

Comment: `std::function<void>` is a nonsense, you need to deduce `f`'s type. You also forgot to expand `args` in the call to `f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
template <typename F, typename... Ts>
void RunFunction(F f, Ts&&... args)
{
    f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}

void testFunction(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << (x + y);
}

int main()
{
    RunFunction(testFunction, 1, 3);
}
```

As

`std::function<void>` is not what you want but `std::function<void(Ts...)>`.
`f(args);` should be `f(args...)`.

And then `Sig` cannot be deduce for `std::function<Sig>` for `testFunction`.

Comment: oh wow that works, is there any chance you could show me how i would be able to add it to a std:vector to call it in a loop of say 3 functions with all having different amounts of args? or should i ask a new question on how to do that? thanks

Comment: I want to be able to store the function + its arguments in a vector, an then call it later when i need it. i have been looking on google to find away and im not having much luck

Comment: That seems to be perfect, I didnt know about these std functions you been using, is it possible to make a function that wraps it to add them to the vector? so that you dont have to add std::bind infront of the function when adding it, and that it also accepts lambda?